# How to group by a "custom field" in a search view? ODOO 10

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

I created a custom field called Commission in the product form (POS module). Its technical name is `x_commission`.
I want to be able to group by "Commission" in the `POS > Reporting > Orders` menu.

Is there a way to access that field from another view?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have a similar problem now, i added a new field but in the model search's view i cannot group by that field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this field on other views of product.product model.

Answer (score 0):

Create the field in a module since as I remember the fields used for group by in read_group method are filtered to be real fields